# How to retrieve youtube videos with a dev key and or dev tag?

Tags: ajax, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm working with the Youtube Data API and I'm trying to retrieve a json feed of videos uploaded with a specific Developer API Key or more preferably with a Developer Tag that is assigned to the videos on upload.

I read the API docs and it said to use this URI:
    http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?key=dev_key_here&v=2&alt=jsonc

That URL gets 100k videos that aren't mine. I should only be getting one video that was uploaded with that my dev key. Any ideas?

I'm going to using ajax to retrieve this dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the API documentation it says that the key is solely used for authentication/identification. If you want to find videos by a user (also your own) then you can use the `author` parameter for specifying that.

The API documentation for this is [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html)

Comment: I'm wanting to retrieve videos from potentially thousands of users with a single parameter, such as the hidden developer tag that I can add to the upload without the user knowing. They will be uploading the videos from an iPhone app that has the key and dev tag hardcoded into every upload.

Comment: wouldn't be possible to hardcode the username, then you could use author for searching?

Comment: Author is only for YT Partners though and we aren't a YT Partner